# PHP 5.4 function update $_POST

Tags: php

I have a script that ran correctly with PHP 5.3.

The code looks like this:

```
  function uihelper_upload_gallery($uid, $_POST, $_FILES, $type, $k=0) {
      require_once "api/User/User.php";
      require_once "api/Tag/Tag.php";
      require_once "api/Album/Album.php";
      require_once "api/Image/Image.php";
      require_once "api/Audio/Audio.php";
      require_once "api/Video/Video.php";
      require_once "web/includes/classes/file_uploader.php";
  }
```

But, on a PHP 5.4 Server I get this error log:

> PHP Fatal error:  Cannot re-assign auto-global variable _POST
>   in.......

What must I do to make this Code PHP 5.4 compatible ?

Comment: Both superglobals (`$_POST` and `$_FILES`) are redundant in the function signature.

Answer (score 0):

you can not name parameters of a function as global variables:

You can edit your function like:

```
 function uihelper_upload_gallery($uid, $POST, $FILES, $type, $k=0) {
      require_once "api/User/User.php";
      require_once "api/Tag/Tag.php";
      require_once "api/Album/Album.php";
      require_once "api/Image/Image.php";
      require_once "api/Audio/Audio.php";
      require_once "api/Video/Video.php";
      require_once "web/includes/classes/file_uploader.php";
  }
```

and pass the value to function when calling

```
uihelper_upload_gallery($uid, $_POST, $_FILES, $type, $k=0);
```

I hope it helps.